# Turning Logistic Binomial Regression with one Continuous and one Categorical predictor into an equation

Tags: r, regression, probability, binomial-coefficients

Basically, I have this data in which the response variable is a binary outcome (1 or 0), no visits or there was a visit. The two predictor variables are Box Height (High or Low) and Distance to Pasture (km). The model works all fine, but I can't seem to find the probability for say, when distance is 0 and box height is High.

```
marsupials <- read.csv("Marsupial_Data.csv") # same with this


###Distance and Height model
fit1 <- glmer(Visit ~ PastureDistance + BoxHeight * (1|Site), data=marsupials, family=binomial(link="logit"))

#summary (gives co-efficients)
summary(fit1) 


#prediction times
# predict using the model
predictions <- predict(fit1, marsupials)
predictions



xv <- seq(min(marsupials$PastureDistance), max(marsupials$PastureDistance), 0.01)
yv <- predict(fitDis, data.frame(PastureDistance = xv), type = "response")


#The Jitter Plot
ggplot(marsupials, aes(PastureDistance, Visit, color = BoxHeight))+
  geom_point(size= 4, position=position_jitter(h=0.02,w=0.00))+ 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "brown"), name = "Nest Box Height")+
  stat_smooth(size = 2, method = "glm", method.args = list(family = binomial), colour = "#4B2D0B")+
  theme_classic()+
  xlab("Distance to Pasture (km)")+
  ylab("Presence")+
  labs(fill = "Box Height")+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=18),
        axis.text = element_text(size=18),
        legend.text = element_text(size=12),
        legend.title = element_text(size=14))
```

Here's my code. I have to apologise as I am really quite new to all this so my explanations and my layout aren't the best.

The summary gives me co-efficients but I can't quite figure out how to interpret them.

Here is an image because I cannot format apparently: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tugQR.png)

i understand if you use exp(-19.064) you are meant to get the probability but this doesn't seem right to me as it gives a probibility of 5.255451e-09 which is uhhh... very small chance.

Here's what my data looks like: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjx8H.png)

Any help would be muchly appreciated

Comment: It's a little hard to read the output.  Can you format that as code so it looks like what R pumps out?

Comment: HI I tried to format it but gave up so there should be a photo

Comment: Looks like the coefficient for PastureDistance is positive.  Is this what you would expect?  Not sure what your study is about, but "More likely to visit if further from pasture" seems like it might be an unexpected result.

Comment: Nah that is actually what we want. It's basically the presence of cows should be scaring marsupials from visiting nest boxes. Which is good and all. I'm just unsure how to use that number and say it in real world terms. Fairly sure it isn't "for every unit increase in distance to pasture, chance of a visit increases by 67%" or something.

Comment: Could you post a histogram of your "distance to pasture" variable?  `hist(marsupials$PastureDistance)` IIRC